# Limiting number of queries to ContentProvider in SearchView

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-searchmanager

I have an **autocomplete** `SearchView` that is managed throught *Search API* and shows a list of locations as suggestions.
The data is provided by a `ContentProvider` in a remote *GAE application*.

The problem that I've is that the `SearchView` makes a query for every letter that the user press.

For example for *New York* it makes 8 queries and I want to limit that because a lot of the queries are wasted because network latency is bigger than user typing latency and for example 'New' is asked before receiving 'Ne'.

I will like a more intelligent behavior like other search components that have some logic to don't do so many queries while the user is actively typing.

PD: A solution using Searchable API or the provider will be better because I use `SearchView` in newer Android versions and search dialog in older ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could at least limit the minimum number of characters typed for starting the search by specifying:

```
android:searchSuggestThreshold
```

in the searchable configuration

Comment: I already knew it. But it's not what I want. In fact I've it to zero because I show some especial suggestions when there isn't any text.

Comment: What I do to limit the number of requests I make is caching the results, especially considering that when users tapes they go forth and back a lot so I always first check the cache and eventually hit the server. The cache is also good because if a user misspell a word I return results going back in the cache.